# Calendar, addressbook access by an app and the data use policy questions

Tags: ios, applications, security, data

When an iOS app seeks permission to access my addressbook or calendar, what is it that they can do with my data? I am thinking of these things.

1. Do they transfer the data from my device to their own servers?
2. Do they keep a copy of the data from my device in their servers? If yes, until when?
3. Does the data obtained from my device get deleted from their servers if I uninstall the app an any point later?
4. Do they anonymize the data if they use it?
5. Can the app developers sell my data? Can they sell it if anonymized(although I don't know how one can anonymize address book data...)

Answers could bring down my growing sense of nervousness each time I allow an app to access my data on my iPhone. Thanks.

Comment: A good answer to this should reference Apple's Developer Agreement and its provisions for enforcement, since what any given app does with your data once given access is up to its developers.

Comment: So basically, this is an Apple issue rather than a developer controlled one, right?

Comment: Well, that depends on what issue you're referring to, specifically. Whether or not you can trust developers with your data? Whether or not Apple should give developers access to your data? Or how fine-grained your control over that access is? The whole concept of an OS-enforced requirement for apps to seek permission before accessing your contacts arose out of this controversy...

Comment: Basically, what sort of answer would be acceptable for this question?

Comment: My initial thought was a yes or no answer to each of the five questions above.